# Is there a convenient tool for viewing/analyzing JSON responses?

Tags: json, testing, editor

I find it inconvenient using my browser to view JSON responses, then copy/paste the code into my editor, then have to put line-breaks in to make it more readable.

It would be great to have a tool that allows me to enter a URL and receive a JSON in a more usable format, like say, a drill-down tree, or at least some color-coding of the text.

What tools are recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox, I've used [JsonViewer](http://www.codeplex.com/JsonViewer) and pasted in my JSON text.

Answer (score 1):

Use the javascript developer window in Google Chrome. You can drill down into any objects.

Just type e.g. "JSON.parse(your_json_string)" and click away!